# Show incorrect answer when using Except method in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want to create a dynamic permission.

The information is sent from the client side and is evaluated in the action if Each of the actions contained in the list sent from the client as well as in the database is ignored and removed from the list.

The client send like this info :

```
0:
 Actions: Array(4)
 0: {ActionId: 100663387}
 1: {ActionId: 100663388}
 2: {ActionId: 100663389}
 3: {ActionId: 100663390}
 controllerID: "35ba32ce-f980-3b9d-a38b-3ca854dcb063"
 roleId: 1004
1:
 Actions: Array(2)
 0: {ActionId: 100663395}
 1: {ActionId: 100663395}
 controllerID: "9a722402-cc69-3ad0-a24e-f1f166a46880"
 roleId: 1004
```

and in ASP.NET Core:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async void AddClaim(List<RecAccessLevel> model, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
        foreach (var item in model)
        {
            var CurrentActions = roleClaimService.TableAsNoTracking
                .Where(x => x.RoleId == item.RoleId && x.ControllerId == item.ControllerID)
                .Select(r => new Action
                {
                    ActionId = r.ActionId
                }).ToList();

            var newActionToAdd = item.Actions.Except(CurrentActions).ToList();

            foreach (var itemAdd in newActionToAdd)
            {
                await roleClaimService.AddAsync(new RoleClaim
                {
                    ActionId = itemAdd.ActionId,
                    ControllerId = item.ControllerID,
                    RoleId = item.RoleId,
                    ClaimType = "DynamicPemission",
                    ClaimValue = string.Format($"{item.RoleId}:{item.ControllerID}:{itemAdd.ActionId}")
                }, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
}
```

The problem is that when I use the method, it does not ignore the matched data

```
public class RecAccessLevel
{
    public string ControllerID { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Action> Actions { get; set; }
}

public class Action
{
    public int ActionId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `Action` class does not implement `GetHashCode` / `Equals`, hence it will be compared by **reference**. And references in this scenario apparently are different even for instances having the same `ActionId`. Either implement the aforementioned methods, or implement and pass to `Except` a custom `IEqualityComparer<Action>`, or work just with ids.

Comment: @IvanStoev i use the `IEqualityComparer<Action>` and its work